# Trying to merge two sections of a business card using CSS and HTML

Tags: css

I am trying to make a business card that has a front and back section.
Here is my code

```
.business-card:hover .front{
    transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(180deg);
}

.business-card .back{
  transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(-180deg);
}

.business-card:hover .back{
    transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(0deg);
}
```

I created classes one called "front" and the other called "back"(BOTH ARE UNDER A CLASS CALLED "business card").

The issue is the code I have written is not working, the front section and the back section are still separate yet I am trying to merge them and basically be able to flip the business card between each section.
Instead, I have the back section appearing below the front section and not together.
What could I have done wrong? I have re-checked my HTML code to make sure everything is okay there and it is.
All my other CSS codes are going through except this one.

Comment: you can provide codepen or codesandbox link it will help in solving the problem

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Source - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp

Code -

````
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}```

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/webdev0904/hnbpuq3j/3/
````